# ServerErrorException when crawling site

Tags: import.io

I am doing a full crawl of a site with the API and I am getting a lot of:

{
  "errorType": "ServerErrorException",
  "error": "ServerErrorException: Server error. (HTTP 500)"
}

Also I am getting timeout responses and actual http fails: `StatusCode: 504, ReasonPhrase: 'GATEWAY_TIMEOUT'`

I am browsing the site I am crawling at same time and it seems fast and responsive still, no slow downs.

I removed multithreading from my code and run synchronously which stops the 500 errors but it still gives lots of timeouts (and takes ages).

I am running less than 100 concurrent connections with my multithreading.  Is that too much?  I'd like to push it to 1000+.  Do I need to add some delay between requests?

Answer (score 3):

The error you are seeing, indicates that the website you are trying to crawl is sending you 500's.

The 504 gateway time-outs you are getting will be because you are possibly hitting import.io with too many requests.

I would slow down your crawling, perhaps setting a delay between requests.

If you are crawling lots of pages, you will have to respect that the website you are crawling might not be able to deal with large amounts of incoming requests in a small amount of time.

I would advise to start slow and increase until you start to see errors/timeouts. Once you start to see some errors, slow down a bit.

Crawling an entire website can be a slow process.

Comment: I reduced it to one request at a time with a second in between requests and it still gets timeouts so I don't think that's it. I put requests in a loop now so timeouts get retried. Import IO is pretty damn quick, I love the service. I get 200 pages scraped in about 12 seconds but that will be much better once I improve my queue code and I've got hundreds of thousands of requests to optimize.  It seems some requests just randomly timeout though.

Comment: I would advise that you catch the ones that fail and re-queue them. This is common practice for crawling websites. When making hundreds of thousands of requests, it's definitely good to have a fallback mechanism if a single request fails, otherwise you'll have to start all your requests again!

Comment: Yeah I did that.  Sometimes the timeout are just a few but sometimes like 40% of requests timeout so a lot of threads get tied up.  I guess it just depends on how busy service is.

Comment: have you tried setting a connection timeout on your end? If you get nothing from import then kill the request, re-queue it and free the thread. At least then you won't have them tied up.

Comment: Got a 60 second timeout set at my end.  I guess I just have to play around with my queue code and various settings to tweak things.